# Grid is flashing while saving the row using using saverow API in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid 3.8.2.When I save the row by calling the saverow API as below,

```
jQuery('#list').jqGrid('saveRow', rowId, '', '', '', afterSaveFunction, saveErrorFunction);
```

my grid flashes for a second and then saves the data and comes back to the normal state.How can I avoid the flashing?

Please help.
Thanks,
Poorna

Comment: What's the code in your `afterSaveFunction` and `saveErrorFunction`?

Comment: In aftersave, i am trying to persist the values edited in the grid as below,

Comment: When i am trying to enter the code, its showing too long..i minimized to the maximum way, still it is showing the same,so ,i am not able to paste the code here.In fact,the values entered in the grid are manipulated and saved as a part of this after save function,

Comment: if its a saveerror function, then it shows an alert to the user that save is failed.